# Spring Controller design pattern inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, maven, inheritance

**Two questions:**

**1:**

All the `Controller`s extend from the `MasterController` and implement its abstract method in every `@GetMapping` in order to have consistency. In every `@Controller` I have to populate the variables inherited from the `MasterController`. There is no assurance that I do all of them all the time. A shortcut would be to call a method from `MasterController` to populate all. Is it possible to catch the same request on multiple places so I do not need to execute the same methods every time but it "gets done" automatically?

```
@SessionAttributes(value = {"user", "..."})
public abstract class MasterController<T>
{
    public Model MODEL;
    public HashMap<String, String> INCOMING_PARAMS;
    public RequestType REQUEST_TYPE;
    public User USER;

    public abstract T request(
            @ModelAttribute("user") User _user,
            @RequestParam HashMap<String, String> _params,
            Model _model,
            SessionStatus _sessionStatus,
            HttpServletRequest _request,
            HttpServletResponse _response);

    public String otherCommonFunction(String _a)
    {
        ...
    }   
}

@Controller
public class LoginController extends MasterController<String>
{
    @GetMapping(value = "/account-login-page")
    @Override
    public String request(
        @ModelAttribute("user") User _user,
        @RequestParam HashMap<String, String>  _params,
        Model _model,
        SessionStatus _sessionStatus,
        HttpServletRequest _request,
        HttpServletResponse _response)
    {
        USER = _user; //Do this every time
        REQUEST_TYPE = RequestType.GET; //Do this every time
        INCOMING_PARAMS = _params; //Do this every time
        MODEL = _model; //Do this every time

        ...

        return "..."
    }
}
```

**2:**

If there are multiple `@GetMapping` in one `@Controller`, how can I have assurance that all of the  methods have exactly the same parameters? An abstract method can be inherited once in the child class. It is possible to just copy and paste it but that looks unprofessional. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: One question: why would you do something like that? You're not doing that just so you can use `otherCommonFunction()` in all controllers, are you? (fine, it was 2 questions, but it started out as one)

Comment: I would advise scrapping your MasterController, it's not giving you anything of value. If you want to ensure certain parameters are mapped then write unit tests. Look into MockMvc.